# Issue installing Hmisc in Rstudio and calling in the library

Tags: r, hmisc

I've had the following error for the package Hmisc. I read another thread which asked more about the error message however it said not to post this as a comment. I've installed the package and received the following error when calling in the library:

```
> library(Hmisc)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Hmisc’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘checkmate’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘Hmisc’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

I've tried deleting the install and then installing checkmate separately and manually installing this from a browser rather than through R directly. However the same error message is returning. Does anyone know how to overcome this? Or similar packages to Hmisc. I need to package for a wtd.quantile function.

Comment: Reinstall with `install.packages("Hmisc",dependecies=T)` Also what's your R version?

Comment: I've used the dependencies=true statement. I'm using version 3.4.0

Comment: Download checkmate and try again

Comment: Yeah I've tried downloading checkmate again but still getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

install.packages('lattice')
library('lattice')

install.packages('survival')
library('survival')

install.packages('Formula')
library('Formula')

install.packages('ggplot2')
library('ggplot2')

install.packages('checkmate')
library('checkmate')

install.packages('htmlwidgets')
library('htmlwidgets')

install.packages('stringi')
library('stringi')

install.packages('Hmisc')
library('Hmisc')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).